# How do I find the mean distance between 2 lines made up of points in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 variables which hold about 30,000 coordinates that construct 2 lines when plotted. The problem is the lines are not necessarily made up of the same number of points and so I can't just do Pythagoras between two points.

My initial thought was to try to find a line of best fit using the points and then create new points at fixed x intervals, then, subtract the y coordinates of each line from the other and take the mean.

Is there a better way to do this, as this will be very efficient to run?

I've added some example lines to illustrate the point.

```
xPos1 <- c(-5,-3.5, -2, -1, 1, 2.5, 3.7, 4, 5)
yPos1 <- c(2,3.5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 14)
xPos2 <- -6:6
yPos2 <- 0:12
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can provide some sample data to demonstrate what you have and what result you are looking for. That will also make it possible for people to test and benchmark potential solutions. Perhaps you can share what it looks like to have a few "lines".

Comment: Are you trying to find the mean distance between every line1 line2 pair of points?  In either case, you definitely should be able to math this out - think about the parallelogram created by drawing lines from each endpoint of the lines.